# Using oracle Rownum with between keyword

Tags: oracle

I am planning to use JDBC Pagination with Oracle (Query based technique ) No caching of results .
When i tried to use rownum with between Option , it didn't gave me any results

select * from mytable  where rownum between 10 and 20;

But this gave me results .

select * from mytable  where rownum < 20;
Please tel me How to solve this ??

Answer (score 4):

I have just answered a very similar question, one way of approaching it would be to do this:

```
select *
from
( select rownum rnum, a.*
from (your_query) a
where rownum <= :M )
where rnum >= :N;
```

Providing a little wrapper for rownum.

I dont think this is wise for large volume implementations however. Although i haven't tested it.

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/855422/oracle-sql-why-does-query-select-from-records-where-rownum-5-and-rownum) for an explanation of why BETWEEN does not work with ROWNUM and [Oracle & Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134025/oracle-pagination), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2134025/oracle-pagination) for how to perform pagination in Oracle queries.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *

FROM (

```
   SELECT rownum   AS rowCount ,ID,UNIT_NAME
   FROM   MWT_COMPANY_UNIT  )
```

WHERE rowCount BETWEEN requiredRowNumMinYouWant AND 
                                                 requiredRowNumMaxYouWant